# What is the best way to store a string variable as a string value in a dictionary?

Tags: python

What is the best way to store a string variable as a string value in a dictionary?

Below I am trying to put a string variable named `authToken` and place it in the dictionary called `header` so I can call it using the requests module

```
if currentTime >= authExpTime:
        getAuthToken()
else:
        header = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':'OAUTH2 access_token=authToken'}
        print header
        for i in metricsCollected:
                callURL = apiURL + i + "?samepletime="
                print callURL
                apiResponse = requests.get(apiURL, headers=header)
                apiResponse.json()
```

Comment: It seems like you are asking how to get the value of authToken into the string that is the value of the 'Authorization' key. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @hlongmore that is exactly it :)

Comment: @That1Guy I think he has a key/value pair (`OAUTH2 access_token=authToken`) within another key/value pair (`'Authorization':'OAUTH2 access_token=authToken'`). A nested dictionary (`{"OAUTH2 access_token" : "authToken"}`) would be better but I didn't know whether his script would allow that or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this. Some are more pythonic than others. The way I would probably do it is:

```
header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'OAUTH2 access_token=%s' % (authToken)
}
```

Comment: I think this is better than my answer since it avoids the confusion/inefficiencies of `+=` for string operations.

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

```
if currentTime >= authExpTime:
        getAuthToken()
else:
        header = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':'OAUTH2 access_token='}
        header["Authorization"] += authToken 
        print header
        for i in metricsCollected:
                callURL = apiURL + i + "?samepletime="
                print callURL
                apiResponse = requests.get(apiURL, headers=header)
                apiResponse.json()
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! much appreciated ;)